# Failed to Call Access Method Exception when Creating a MedicationOrder in FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, hapi, dstu2-fhir, hapi-fhir

I am using [this](http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2) http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu2 test FHIR server and it worked okay so far.
Now I am getting an HTTP-500 - Failed to Call Access Method exception.
Anyone has any idea on what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens frequently. Probably because someone tested weird queries or similar that put the server in an unstable status.

I suggest posting a comment in https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/hapi to get the server restarted, 
or install http://hapifhir.io/doc_cli.html which does basically the same but you have full control.

I built a Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:sid

MAINTAINER Günter Zöchbauer <guenter@yyy.com>

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive

RUN \
  apt-get -q update && \
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && \
  apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y -q \
    apt-transport-https \
    apt-utils \
    wget \
    bzip2 \
    default-jdk

#  net-tools sudo procps telnet
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

https://github.com/jamesagnew/hapi-fhir/releases/download/v2.0/hapi-fhir-2.0-cli.tar.bz2 && \

ADD hapi-* /hapi_fhir_cli/

RUN ls -la
RUN ls -la /hapi_fhir_cli

ADD prepare_server.sh /hapi_fhir_cli/

RUN \
  cd /hapi_fhir_cli && \
  bash -c /hapi_fhir_cli/prepare_server.sh

ADD start.sh /hapi_fhir_cli/

WORKDIR /hapi_fhir_cli

EXPOSE 5555

ENTRYPOINT ["/hapi_fhir_cli/start.sh"]
```

Which requires in the same directory as the `Dockerfile`

**`prepare_server.sh`**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ls -la
./hapi-fhir-cli run-server --allow-external-refs &
while ! timeout 1 bash -c "echo > /dev/tcp/localhost/8080"; do sleep 10; done
./hapi-fhir-cli upload-definitions -t http://localhost:8080/baseDstu2
./hapi-fhir-cli upload-examples -c -t http://localhost:8080/baseDstu2
```

**`start.sh`**

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /hapi_fhir_cli
./hapi-fhir-cli run-server --allow-external-refs -p 5555
```

Build

```bash
docker build myname/hapi_fhir_cli_dstu2 -t . #--no-cache
```

Run

```bash
docker run -d -p 5555:5555 [image id from docker build]
```

Hope this helps.